# Undefined reference while trying to implement an interface in C

Tags: c, struct, interface, linker

I was reading up on implementing interfaces in C and I really wanted to give it a shot. I thought I knew how to do it but I am stuck on one last piece of the puzzle. I can't continue without breaking **encapsulation**. I have two "Objects", "Fruit" and "Apple". I want the user to handle Fruit objects but never know the underlying type (Apple in this case).

I can't seem to do it because I cannot find a way for `Apple` to know how to create itself with `Fruit`. I do not want to allow `Main.c` to see `constructor` but `Apple.c` needs to see it. I don't know how to proceed.

I have the following project structure:

Fruit.h

```
// fruit is too general to be created here
// fruit objects can only be created in other files
typedef struct Fruit Fruit;
void grow(Fruit *f);
```

Fruit.c

```
#include "Fruit.h"
// It's very important user cannot see 'struct Fruit'
struct Fruit 
{ 
    void *fruit_obj;    // Fruit object of unknown type
    void(*grow)(void*); // grow function for that type of fruit 
};

// User should not see this!
// Fruit objects can only be made from other files!
Fruit* constructor(void *fruit_obj, void(*grow)(void*))
{
    Fruit *f = malloc(sizeof(Fruit));
    f->fruit_obj = fruit_obj;
    f->grow = grow;
    return f;
}

void grow(Fruit *f)
{
    f->grow(f->fruit_obj);
}
```

Apple.h

```
#include "Fruit.h"
Fruit* createApple();
```

Apple.c

```
#include "Apple.h"
// The user should never ever see this struct.
struct Apple
{
    int size;
}

void apple_grow(void *a)
{
    struct Apple *apple = (struct Apple*)a;
    apple->size++;
    printf("Your apple has grown to %d size!\n", apple->size);
}

// My attempt to make me able to create fruit from this file.
extern Fruit* constructor(void *fruit_obj, void(*grow)(void*));
Fruit* createApple()
{
    struct Apple *a = malloc(sizeof(struct Apple));
    a->size = 1;
    Fruit *f = constructor(a, &apple_grow);
    // LINKER ERROR: 'undefined reference to 'constructor''
    return f;
}
```

Main.c

```
#include "Apple.h"
int main()
{
    Fruit *f = createApple();
    grow(f);
}
```

Comment: You can have more than one header. "private" headers are not uncommon.

Comment: @StoryTeller How is this done?

Comment: There's a whole book on the subject, by Axel-Tobias Schreiner. You can read a free online version of it here: http://www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/ooc.pdf

Comment: @StoryTeller This is actually what I was reading. I didn't read any part about encapsulation yet. I saw structures and function pointers being the critical components so I started with that.

Comment: Then you just need to carry on reading :) The book covers it.

Comment: @StoryTeller Okay I will. But in regards to the issue at hand, a private header file can solve this? I guess there's nothing that stops the user from including that private header file of course

Comment: Only if the user can get their hands on it